# Which files & folders do I replace in order to upgrade Magento 2 manually?

Tags: magento2.3, magento-upgrade, magento2.4, command-line, ubuntu

Which files and folders need to be replaced in the Magneto root folder in order to upgrade Magento 2 Manually?

I am running a stock copy of `Mangento 2.3.5` on a `Ubuntu 18.04` test server.

I am trying to upgrade from `Mangento 2.3.5` to `Magento 2.4.1`

So far I have installed `php 7.4`, the required php extensions and `elasticsearch 7.6`. I have downloaded a copy of `Magneto 2.4.1`

I know this could be achieved via composer and then using the Magento upgrade command. However, I would like to know how to go about doing this manually, so I could keep track of what is changed and learn the processes that take place during an upgrade.

I appreciate any help that you could provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mangaged to upgrade manually by extracting Magento 2.4.1 `tar.bz2` file within the Magento root directory.  This replaced all the necessary files in order to upgrade:

`tar -xvf magento-ce-2.4.1-2020-09-25-04-22-45.tar.bz2`

I then set the correct permissions within the Magento root directory using these commands:

`find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +`

`find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +`

`chmod u+x bin/magento`

`chown -R maguser:www-data .`

****(my server username for managing Magento is** `maguser`.   **Yours will be different.)**

Then use the upgrade command:

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Finally, I re-indexed, cleaned and flushed the cache:

`php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

`php bin/magento cache:clean`

`php bin/magento cache:flush`

Starting from Magento 2.4, 2-factor authentication (2fa) is enabled by default.  If you need to disable this in order to access your admin login page, you could do this by issuing the following commands:

`php bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth`

`php bin/magento cache:flush`